# Взятие объекта по адресу в конструторе копирования

Tags: c++

Всем добрый день. Стандартный конструктор копирования в классе выглядит так: `SomeClass(const SomeClass &obj)`
Как я понимаю, const отвечают за то, что в процессе его работы объект не может быть изменен и отвечает по большей степени за безопасность кода. Тогда подскажите, зачем в конструктор копирования передается объект по ссылке, а не по значению, если он все равно const.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В конструкторе копирования нужна именно ссылка на объект, так как если мы попробуем передавать объект по значению, то будем вызывать конструктор копирования внутри себя:

```
class Foo {
     public:
    Foo(const Foo&){
            std::cout << "copy constructor";
        };
    Foo(){}
};
void f(Foo) {
}
```

Если попробовать вызывать функцию `f`, то можно увидеть, что при передаче объекта по значению вызывается конструктор копирования. Представим себе, что теперь в конструктор копирования можно было бы передать объект по значению, тогда для того, чтобы передать этот объект пришлось вызвать бы конструктор копирования, а внутри него снова конструктор копирования... Ясна проблема?

Comment: Да понял большое спасибо